# Cannot assign current buffer name in let statement

Tags: buffers, variables, lexical-scoping, let-binding

I'm trying to write some buffer switching function (which in itself may be a fool's errand, but I digress...) - and it looks a little like this

```
(defun swk--quit-buffer (original-buffer)
  (switch-to-buffer (original-buffer))
  (kill-buffer "*tmp*")
  (local-unset-key "q"))

(defun swk-switcheroo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((temp-buf-name "*tmp*")
        (current-buffer-name (buffer-name)))
    (get-buffer-create temp-buf-name)
    (switch-to-buffer temp-buf-name)
    (local-set-key "q" (lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (swk--quit-buffer current-buffer-name)))))
```

My aim is to be able to temporarily bind "q" to this window, to simulate special-mode's "quittable" buffer. Sure enough, the "q" key works once, but I get the message:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void current-buffer-name
```

Ideally, I want to replace the current buffer with the result of invoking swk-switcheroo - and then reinstate the original buffer when the user presses "q".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're tripping over dynamic binding (as opposed to lexical binding).

Your `current-buffer-name` is unbound at the point that your (lambda) function is executed. The `let` expression only binds it during the function's *definition* -- there's no closure to capture that value for subsequent evaluation.

One simple workaround is to use backquoting like so:

```el
`(lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (swk--quit-buffer ',current-buffer-name))
```

Comment: so how would I go about capturing that information? is this approach non-idiomatic? i've taken a look at save-excursion and display-buffer - perhaps they are better alternatives?

Comment: @sunwukung Since Emacs 24, the idiomatic way would be to [enable lexical binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html#Using-Lexical-Binding). In earlier versions, phils' method is the best you can do.